# Could not find gem 'jquery-rails (>= 0, runtime)' in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile. Trying to start rails server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu-11.04

Source: http://rubygems.org

```
gem 'rails', '3.1.0'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails',     :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

gem 'sqlite3'

gem 'json'

# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails', "  ~> 3.1.0"
  gem 'coffee-rails', "~> 3.1.0"
  gem 'uglifier'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'

# Use unicorn as the web server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Deploy with Capistrano
# gem 'capistrano'

# To use debugger
# gem 'ruby-debug'
```

Does anyone have any ideas here? Yes, I tried `bundle install`.

Answer (score 0):

You have not declared any sources. Add

```
source "http://rubygems.org"
```

to the top of the file (or, if that line at the top of your question is actually in the file, modify it to be exactly like that).